# Directory traversal to root or home from any location

Tags: directory, filenames

Param is my input, which is added to the cat command so basically 
`eval "cat /a/really/long/path/idk/how/long/$param1"` on changing the param1 to something to something else can I access the home/root without having to bruteforce the `../`'s, is there a syntax which lets me jump directly to root or home so 
`cat '/a/really/long/path/idk/how/long' + $param1` becomes
`cat '/a/really/long/path/idk/how/long/SYNTAX-To-HOME/.bashrc`.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `+ $param`. Taken literally, you concatenate three files, one with a long pathname, one named `+`, one whose name is in the `param` variable. It's not clear either what you mean by "jump to root or home". Do you want to transform the long pathname into `$HOME/.bashrc` without having access to the `cat` command?

Answer (score 0):

If you can only choose a suffix of a file name, and you want to display a path starting from the root directory, using a sufficient amount of `../` is the only way. There's no way to "restart" a path from the root directory midway. There's also no way to to refer to a home directory in a file, so you need to use something like `../../../../../home/username` (again, with enough `../`), assuming the user's home directory is `/home/username`.

Some applications perform additional expansions on file names, but it's unusual. The one expansion that's moderately common in *interactive* applications is to expand `~/` at the very beginning of the path. Command line applications don't do even this because this kind of expansion is the shell's job.

The required number of `../` may or may not be the number of path components in the prefix that you don't control, because symbolic links change the effective depth. For example, if `/dir`, `/foo` and `/foo/bar` are directories and `/foo/sym` is a symbolic link to `/dir`, `/foo/bar/..` is the root directory. But if `/sym` is a symbolic link to `/foo/bar`, then `/sym/..` is `/foo`, and you need `/sym/../..` to get back to the root directory.

Having too many `../` doesn't hurt unless you run into a limit on the length of the path.

Another potential method could be to rely on a symbolic link to a directory further up. But that requires such a symbolic to exist, and you to know about it. A mount point (e.g. `mount --bind / /a/really/long/path/root`) can also let you escape a directory tree.

Note that my answer so far discusses file names. If you can inject a *shell command*, as in `eval "cat /a/really/long/path/idk/how/long/$param1"`, the way paths are parsed is irrelevant: just inject shell special characters, e.g. set `param1` to `nonexistent || true; cat /the/file/I/want`.

Comment: > without having to bruteforce the `../`
maybe he doesn't know how long the `../`'s are so doesn't want to manually test for each situation. But the last paragraph seems very clear.